# Store data in an array using for each in node js sequelize

Tags: node.js, arrays, foreach, sequelize.js

I am trying to push the fetched data in an array using foreach but it only returns the first data in the loop. Here is my code.

```
exports.getAllTrial = async function (req, res, next) {

try {
    
    new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        var reservations = [];
        await Schedule.getSchedule()
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(async (element) => { 
                await saveReserve.getAllTrial({where: {scheduleID: element.id, date: "8/18/2020"}})
                .then(trial => {
                    trial.forEach(response => { 
                        reservations.push(response.scheduleID)
                    })
                }) 
                console.log(reservations);
                resolve(reservations);
            })
        });
    })

    .then(value=>{
        res.status(200).json(value);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

} catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: e.message });
}
```

}

My expected output should be: [ 9, 10, 10 ] But it only returns [9].

Answer (score 2):

Async code in a foreach loop is a bad idea, as it won't be executed one after the other. I suggest reading a bit more async/await and the concept of promise, as you are mixing things here (such as mixing `await` and `.then`). Also worth looking into `Promise.all` which will resolve a list of promises and `array.map`.

While I have no idea of what some variables such as `saveReserve` are supposed to be or do, your code might be simplified into:

```
exports.getAllTrial = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = await Schedule.getSchedule()

    const reservations = await Promise.all(
      data.map(element => {
        return saveReserve.getAllTrial({ where: { scheduleID: element.id, date: '8/18/2020' } })
      })
    )

    return res.status(200).json(reservations)
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: e.message })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Yes i'll learn more about it. :)

Comment: How can I push an array inside the data.map because I have to get the data from the getSchedule and push with the fetched data from getAllTrial

Comment: Th reservations variable will contain the results of all getAll calls, and data contains the result of getSchedule. If data is an array, then you can just use .concat to have a final array with the content of both. It just sound weird to have different type of data in the same array ?